# for loop control in bash using a string

Tags: bash

I want to use a string to control a for loop in bash. My first test code produces what I would expect and what I want:

```
$ aa='1 2 3 4'
$ for ii in $aa; do echo $ii; done
1
2
3
4
```

I'd like to use something like the following instead. This doesn't give the output I'd like (I can see why it does what it does).

```
$ aa='1..4'
$ for ii in $aa; do echo $ii; done
1..4
```

Any suggestions on how I should modify the second example to give the same output as the first?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts. I'm slowly learning bash but still have a lot to learn.

Mike

Comment: Why do you want to use a string to create a sequence of numbers? Can you give an example where `for ((i=1; i<5; i++)); do …; done` is insufficient?

Answer (score 2):

The notation could be written out as:

```
for ii in {1..4}; do echo "$ii"; done
```

but the `{1..4}` needs to be written out like that, no variables involved, and not as the result of variable substitution.  That is [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) in the Bash manual, and it happens before string expansions, etc.  You'll probably be best off using:

```
for ii in $(seq 1 4); do echo "$ii"; done
```

where either the 1 or the 4 or both can be shell variables.

Comment: The use of `seq` makes me question the whole _string_ thing, since an arithmetic `for` loop is almost certainly better.

Comment: That's another way to do it, @kojiro, for sure.  It might be better.  I still tend to use shell notations that are not exclusive to Bash, but the question is tagged `bash` so you could provide that as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `seq` command (see `man seq`).

```
$ aa='1 4'
$ for ii in $(seq $aa); do echo $ii; done
```

Comment: This does not accept a string as input as described by the question.

Answer (score 1):

Bash won't do [brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) with variables, but you can use `eval`:

```
$ aa='1..4'
$ for ii in $(eval echo {$aa}); do echo $ii; done
1
2
3
4
```

You could also split `aa` into an array:

```
IFS=. arr=($aa) 
for ((ii=arr[0]; ii<arr[2]; ii++)); do echo $ii; done
```

Note that `IFS` can only be a single character, so the .. range places the numbers into indexes 0 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** There are certainly more elegant ways of doing this, as Ben Grimm's answer, and this is not pure bash, as uses seq and awk.

One way of achieving this is by calling `seq`. It would be trivial if you knew the numbers in the string beforehand, so there would be no need to do any conversion, as you could simple do `seq 1 4` or `seq $a $b` for that matter.

I assume, however, that your input is indeed a string in the format you mentioned, that is, `1..4` or `20..100`. For this purpose you could convert the string into 2 numbers ans use them as parameters for `seq`.

One of possibly many ways of achieving this is:

```
$ `echo "1..4" | sed -e 's/\.\./ /g' | awk '{print "seq", $1, $2}'`
1
2
3
4
```

Note that this will work the same way for any input in the given format. If desired, `sed` can be changed by `tr` with similar results.

```
$ x="10..15"
$ `echo $x | tr "." " " | awk '{print "seq", $1, $2}'`
10
11
12
13
14
15
```